# 'setMapTypeId' not working with custom map (Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a set of different map types (styles). As you can see in the simplified example, I try to switch the map types with an onClick event.

This works great for the default - by google.maps provided - styles. But when I try to switch to my custom style, I have a delay of ~2-3 seconds (local environment) and then get a completely grey map (nothing on the tiles).

I know that the map style itself works (not the same as in the linked example), because it's my initial map style. So only the switch back to my custom style is not working. Sadly I get nothing in the console and don't know how I could debug this.

```
<?php
// Inside the init(); function:
?>
var custom_style = [
     {
         featureType: 'water'
        ,stylers: [
             { hue: "#009ee0" }
            ,{ saturation: 100 }
            ,{ lightness: 0 }
         ]
     }
];
var CUSTOMMAPTYPE = new google.maps.StyledMapType( 
    custom_style, 
    // Options:
    { 
        alt: "Show Custom style",
        name: "custom" 
    } 
);

<?php
// Inside the view
$map_types = array(
     'Roadmap'
    ,'Terrain'
    ,'Satellite'
    ,'Hybrid'
    ,'CustomMapType'
);
foreach ( $map_types as $index => $type )
{
    ?>
    <span 
        class="map-type" 
        onClick="
                my_map.setMapTypeId( google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo strtoupper( $type ); ?> );
                // This is funny: I can access all mapType objects without a problem:
                console.log( my_map.mapTypes.<?php echo strtolower( $type ); ?> );
            " 
        id="<?php echo strtolower( $type ); ?>"
    >
        <?php echo $type; ?>
    </span>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:**

Here's something other I tried (from inside my `init();` fn, that does the setup for the map):

```
// The map type control DOM/UI Element
var map_type_controls = document.getElementsByClassName( 'map-type' );

// using jQuery to add a DOM listener function for click events to the UI elements:
jQuery.each( map_type_controls,  function() {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( this, 'click', function() {
        var control_id = jQuery( this ).attr( 'id' );
        var control = control_id.toUpperCase();

                // uncomment to debug:
                // Shows all map type control DOM element correct
        // console.log( control );
                // Shows all registered mapType objects incl. the custom one correct:
                // console.log( my_map.mapTypes );

        my_map.setMapTypeId( google.maps.MapTypeId[ control ] );

                // Per recommendation - doesn't help
        google.maps.event.trigger( atlas_map, "resize" );
    } ); 
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you modified a property of a map, let's say a new coordinates or a zoom, even if you change the size of the container (div), you should trigger the event called `resize` it's the only way to avoid this problem, now, i don't know if this works when you change the type of the map but you should try, the code it's the following:

```
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

Comment: in the javascript part of the event onclick after you set the type of the map. in your case  your object it's not called map but mymap, take that in consideration

Comment: I see what you mean. The only advantage of adding this is that the delay now is longer until I get a grey map :). Btw: Switching back works without a problem. I can't get rid of the feeling, that my map_type has some sort of problem...

Comment: I added an edit: `console.log( my_map.mapTypes.<?php echo strtolower( $type ); ?> );`, which shows me that i def. have the object available. Sadly no progress :P

Comment: which type of the map are looking bad when you make the selection

Comment: The custom one. It's gets plain empty grey. When I click on one of the DOM elements that trigger the default/google map types, then it switches back without a problem. Due to the fact that the custom type is my initial map type and displays fine (until I click the element), I can't debug anything, as it doesn't look like an error.

Comment: See update. I already tried another - close to working - solution with the same result. Do you think the registration of my mapType could be causing this?

Comment: i really think so, because there's not other explanation, what do you want to accomplish with this custom style??

Comment: I'll mark your answer as solution and hope that the following readers, will take a look at [this](http://pastie.org/2498213) link. The problem wasn't the map style itself, but more the documentation. The docs tell that you should use `google.maps.MapTypeId.MAPTYPE` inside the set function, which is wrong. As you can see in the paste-link, you simply pass a string and everything is ok. This took close to a whole day - sadly. But resolved now. Thanks for your time & help, mate!